# dataframe combine_first does not work as well as fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

the first dataframe is:

```
   data_date cookie_type   dau  next_dau  dau_7  dau_15
0   20181006    avg(0-d)  2288       NaN    NaN     NaN
1   20181006    avg(e-f)  2284       NaN    NaN     NaN
2   20181007    avg(e-f)  2296       100    NaN     NaN
```

the second dataframe is :

```
  data_date cookie_type  next_dau
0  20181006    avg(e-f)       908
1  20181006    avg(0-d)       904
```

how to update the first dataframe's next_dau from the second one
i have tried combine_first and fillna, they seem not support multi-index:

```
cols = ['data_date', 'cookie_type']

    if (frame1 is not None and not frame1.empty):
        frame1.set_index(cols)
        print(frame1)
        print(next_day_dau)
        frame1.combine_first(next_day_dau.set_index(cols))
        frame1.combine_first(dau_7.set_index(cols))
        frame1.combine_first(dau_15.set_index(cols))
```

then i updated to:

```
frame1.index = frame1.data_date.astype(str) + frame1.cookie_type
        next_day_dau.index = next_day_dau.data_date.astype(str) + next_day_dau.cookie_type
        dau_7.index = dau_7.data_date.astype(str) + dau_7.cookie_type
        dau_15.index = dau_15.data_date.astype(str) + dau_15.cookie_type
        """frame1.loc[next_day_dau.index, "next_dau"] = next_day_dau.next_dau
        frame1.loc[dau_7.index, "dau_7"] = dau_7.dau_7
        frame1.loc[dau_15.index, "dau_15"] = dau_15.dau_15"""
        frame1.combine_first(next_day_dau)
        frame1.combine_first(dau_7)
        frame1.combine_first(dau_15)
        print(frame1)
        print(next_day_dau)
```

loc raise a error because of next_day_dau dose not contain all the indexes in frame1 then i tried combine-first and fillna with inplace=True ,all dont work.[image]

```
{'data_date': {'20181007avg(0-d)': 20181007, '20181007avg(e-f)': 20181007, '20181006avg(0-d)': 20181006, '20181006avg(e-f)': 20181006}, 'cookie_type': {'20181007avg(0-d)': 'avg(0-d)', '20181007avg(e-f)': 'avg(e-f)', '20181006avg(0-d)': 'avg(0-d)', '20181006avg(e-f)': 'avg(e-f)'}, 'dau': {'20181007avg(0-d)': 2288, '20181007avg(e-f)': 2284, '20181006avg(0-d)': 2288, '20181006avg(e-f)': 2284}, 'next_dau': {'20181007avg(0-d)': nan, '20181007avg(e-f)': nan, '20181006avg(0-d)': nan, '20181006avg(e-f)': nan}, 'dau_7': {'20181007avg(0-d)': nan, '20181007avg(e-f)': nan, '20181006avg(0-d)': nan, '20181006avg(e-f)': nan}, 'dau_15': {'20181007avg(0-d)': nan, '20181007avg(e-f)': nan, '20181006avg(0-d)': nan, '20181006avg(e-f)': nan}}
{'data_date': {0: '20181007', 1: '20181007'}, 'cookie_type': {0: 'avg(e-f)', 1: 'avg(0-d)'}, 'next_dau': {0: 2284, 1: 2288}}
```

Comment: You have default indexes in the dataframes you are showing in this question.  Can you do a df1.to_dict() and df2.to_dict() ?

Comment: i update the frame.to_dict()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved this problem with help from "tianhua liao":

```
frame1.index = frame1.data_date.astype(str) + frame1.cookie_type
next_day_dau.index = next_day_dau.data_date.astype(str) + next_day_dau.cookie_type
dau_7.index = dau_7.data_date.astype(str) + dau_7.cookie_type
dau_15.index = dau_15.data_date.astype(str) + dau_15.cookie_type
# get_index
next_day_dau_idx = frame1.index.isin(next_day_dau.index)
dau_7_idx = frame1.index.isin(dau_7.index)
dau_15_idx = frame1.index.isin(dau_15.index)
#
if any(next_day_dau_idx):
    frame1.loc[next_day_dau_idx, "next_dau"] = next_day_dau.next_dau
if any(dau_7_idx):
    frame1.loc[dau_7_idx, "dau_7"] = dau_7.dau_7
if any(dau_15_idx):
    frame1.loc[dau_15_idx, "dau_15"] = dau_15.dau_15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `merge` to solve your use-case. More documentation is here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

```
 print(t1)
  cookie_type  data_date  next_dau
0    avg(0-d)   20181006       1
1    avg(e-f)   20181006       2
2    avg(e-f)   20181007       NaN

    print(t2)
  cookie_type  data_date  next_dau
0    avg(e-f)   20181006       908
1    avg(0-d)   20181006       904
2    avg(e-f)   20181007       905
```

`result = pd.merge(t1, t2, on=['data_date', 'cookie_type'])`

```
  cookie_type  data_date  next_dau_x  next_dau_y
0    avg(0-d)   20181006         1         904
1    avg(e-f)   20181006         2         908
2    avg(e-f)   20181007         NaN       905
```

Now, to update only **Not Nan** values, you can use `where` clause.

`result['col'] = result['next_dau_x'].where(result['next_dau_x'].notnull(), result['next_dau_y'])`

Now, drop the columns which are not required.

`result = result.drop(['next_dau_x','next_dau_y'], axis=1)`

```
  cookie_type  data_date    col
0    avg(0-d)   20181006     1
1    avg(e-f)   20181006     2
2    avg(e-f)   20181007     905
```

Comment: next_dau from the first frame may be not Nan

Comment: ok, if values of next_dau is not Nan in 1st Frame, do you want to preserve those and update only the Nan values?